# Ubuntu won't detect my RAW USB

Tags: usb, read-only, mp3-player, detect

It was working before I got a "read-only", "waste-basket not detected" error when trying to delete something. I think this may be because the USB became partially disconnected? Other computers asked me to reformat it or nothing.

Comment: Maybe flash memory died. It becomes read-only first. That happens.

Comment: Sansa product? Running Rockbox? Tell us more.

Comment: I was wrong Pilot6, computers that detect it want me to reformat.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the update icon ( or type 'update' in tge search window. If that doesn't work type system recovery in the search tab and see if that helps. Sometimes a hardware issue may be to blame if you have Ububuntu solely on the PC you are using.